# network performance measurement and use of wifi and cellular at same time.is it possible on android?

Tags: android, android-studio, network-programming, wifi, cellular-network

I'm working on a project for my master. I am trying to create an app with android studio that mesures network performance (downlaod speed,latency,jitter) for WiFi and cellular data,then choose between them. One problem is that while using wifi (or celllar) i must be able to verify the performance of cellular (or Wifi).that means that i must use dataand wifi at the same time.Is it possible on android? is there anyone who's capable to help me? I'll be very greatfull.

Comment: On any system, at a given time, you can only use one means for data transfer. It is not possible to use cellular and wifi network at the same time.

Comment: i found some apps that use the same idea;it's called SPEEDIFY and i guess rooted phone can do it.i just can't find that code :(. thanks for your answer